# When compile the CLIPS integration source code,the CLIPSStatic in the CLIPS Solution is failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, integration, clips

I have checked the updated code from the weibsite: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/

When I build the CLPSStactic project, there is an error displayed in the output window:

```
..\clipscpplib.cpp(281):error C2664: 

"EnvAddRouterWithContext": cannot convert parameter 4 from "int (__cdecl *)(void *,const char *) to "int (__cdecl *)()""
```

Notes：

1. I use the VS2012 version
2. Using VS2012 open the CLIPS.sln(in the folder named "Installer")
   has errors in updating to vs2012(CLIPS.vdproj, CLIPSSource.vdproj). But the CLIPS's source code has generated in the folder ../Source/CLIPS.
3. CLIPSDynamic and CLIPSWrapper can be compiled without errors.

I want to know why this error come out, is it related to the VS version or anything else? How to solve this?

Thank you!

---

@Gary Riley
If you have time, please take a look at this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong projects/solutions. Download the latest commit (r281). The solution folders in the microsoft_windows directory that you want to use are CLIPS_MVC_2010, CLIPS_MVC_2013, Examples_MVC_2010, and Examples_MVC_2013. Since you're using Visual Studio 2012, you'll probably want to use the 2010 directories. The instructions in the Advanced Programming Guide specifically reference these directories. Don't use anything in the Installer directory. You'll need to copy the CLIPS source code files from the core directory to the microsoft_windows/Source/CLIPS directory since these aren't replicated in the repository.

Comment: I made it. Thank you very very very very very much ! ^_^   //Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by myself. There's the details:

1. Copy the "router.h" and "router.c" files from the folder "core" (http://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/) 
   to the folder "microsoft_windows/Source/CLIPS", and delete both origin files in the folder "../CLIPS".
2. Don't copy all the files in the folder "core" to "CLIPS". it won't make the CLIPSStatic project built successful either. It seems there are problems in  "aggenda.h" or "aggenda.c" of the folder "core".
3. I think the problem is that the "router.h" and "router.c" generated by the project CLIPS in the folder named "Installer" isn't the newest version.

If you have check the code from the same website, and used the same version VS. you may encounter this problem too. And this manner can help you to solve the problem.